# How to make element fill percentage of screen and also be zoomable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a square with CSS that is equal to 90% of the smaller between `width` and `height` of it's parent body. I have achieved this using `vmin` and also tried it with `aspect-ratio: 1`.

This works but the issue is that on PC the user cannot zoom in on the square using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd> and for some reason it works on mobile - probably because of the `user-scalable="yes"` attribute inside the Viewport `meta` tag.

I would like to achieve the same result on a PC preferably using CSS only but I can use JavaScript too.

One possible solution would be to somehow distinguish between resize and zoom in and only trigger the function on resize, but like I said above I would prefer a CSS only solution.

```js
window.onresize = resizeSquare;

function resizeSquare() {
  let size = Math.min(document.querySelector("body").offsetWidth, document.querySelector("body").offsetHeight) * 0.9;
  document.querySelector("#square").style.width = size + "px";
  document.querySelector("#square").style.height = size + "px";
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

div#square {
  width: 90vmin;
  height: 90vmin;
  background-color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<div id="square"></div>
```

Comment: The simple answer is to not use `vmin` units, as they are set to the viewport size and are agnostic of zoom level. That's the sole cause of your problem.

Comment: How would I achieve 90% of parent without vmin, using percentages on body is the same as using viewport units if I am not mistaken (if I used rem I would have to use a lot of media queries)

Comment: There is really no difference between zooming and scaling the viewport from website's point of view. When you click `ctrl +` you just make the viewport smaller.